# How to calculate subnets

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, subnet

It's been a while and haven't been able to figure out how I can subnet the below ranges. Could someone help me to subnet these ranges and provide some insight?

```
Subnet the 10.0.0.0/8 address space into 30 subnets.
Subnet the 172.16.0.0 address space into 13 subnets.
Subnet the 192.168.1.0/24 address space into 4 subnets.
Subnet the 192.168.0.0/24 address space into 7 subnets.
```

Comment: This is off-topic as it's not a programming question.  Also, just check e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnetting.

Answer (score 5):

I love to solve problems on IP sub-netting.
I will teach for the 1st problem and you can do the rest by yourself.
Following are the steps:

1. Write the given networks address with its subnet mask.
   10.0.0.0 / 8   =>  we can not change the first 8 bits, N=8.
2. Write it in binary form with each octet separated by .
   ***000001010*** . 00000000 . 00000000. 00000000   /8
3. Now comes the question, how many subnets do you need.
   in this case : 30 subnets
4. Find the next nearest power of 2, 2^5 = 32 (nearest to 30)
5. The number for bits required to subnet, M=5
6. Leave out the first N bits (step 1), and for the next M bits, write all the binary combination.
   In our example, first 8 bits remain same, then we write all 5 bit combination and append it.
    1st:  ***000001010*** . **00000**000 . 00000000. 00000000  /13  N+M
    2nd:  ***000001010*** . **00001**000 . 00000000. 00000000  /13 N+M
    3rd:  ***000001010*** . **00010**000 . 00000000. 00000000  /13 
    .
    30th subnet:  ***000001010*** . **11101**000 . 00000000. 00000000  /13
    31th subnet:  ***000001010*** . **11110**000 . 00000000. 00000000  /13
    32nd sunbet:  ***000001010*** . **11111**000 . 00000000. 00000000  /13
7. Convert each thing to the decimal equivalent and you will get 32 different subnets.
   I hope its clear.

Answer (score 3):

I have done 2, the rest is upto you! Also have [a look here](http://www.thenetworkadministrator.com/hack/SubnetAddressing.htm), it will help you refresh your memory :)

**10.0.0.0/8 - 30 subnets**

```
N = network - S = subnet - H = host

10.0.0.0 = NNNNNNNN.HHHHHHHH.HHHHHHHH.HHHHHHHH /8
```

We need 30 subnets, so 2^5 = 32 subnets *(provides 524286 usable hosts [2^19 - 2])*

```
10.0.0.0 = NNNNNNNN.SSSSSHHH.HHHHHHHH.HHHHHHHH /13

1: 10.0.0.0/13 
2: 10.8.0.0/13
3: 10.16.0.0/13
...
30th: 10.232.0.0/13
```

**192.168.1.0/24 - 4 subnets**

```
192.168.1.0 = NNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN.HHHHHHHH /24
```

We need 4 subnets, so 2^2 = 4 subnets *(provides 62 usable hosts [2^6 - 2])*

```
192.168.1.0 = NNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN.SSHHHHHH /26

1: 192.168.1.0/26
2: 192.168.1.64/26
3: 192.168.1.128/26
4: 192.168.1.192/26
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a simple binary mask (i.e. perform AND between the make and the number to resolve the network's address, remaining is host id). There is more detailed information [here](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/cisco/30.1_Quick_subnet_calculating_techniques) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnetting).